# Why comparing varchar/number works

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Why this block gives no error with NULL; inside. And raises error (ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error) with any other instruction inside?

```
BEGIN
  IF 'x' = 1 THEN
    NULL;
  --dbms_output.put_line('test');
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 6):

What I think is happening in your case is that you have the compilation parameter [`PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-364B752A-4335-468C-B4BA-AAC32D75385A.htm#REFRN10255) set to a value that's high enough to allow the compiler to optimise your code.

So, when you have `NULL;` inside your `IF` statement, it can be rewritten to remove that `IF` statement when compiled.

However, with something other than `NULL;` present inside the `IF` statement, it can no longer be removed, so the check `'x' = 1` is then made. Oracle will convert character values to numbers if it's being compared to a number, so in your case that means the comparison fails because `x` is not a number.

E.g.:

The following works:

```
ALTER SESSION SET plsql_optimize_level = 2;

BEGIN
  IF 'x' = 1 THEN
    NULL;
    --dbms_output.put_line('test');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

But the following fails:

```
ALTER SESSION SET plsql_optimize_level = 1;

BEGIN
  IF 'x' = 1 THEN
    NULL;
    --dbms_output.put_line('test');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

The only difference is the `PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL` value - 2 or higher, and the compiler will optimize away the irrelevant `IF` statement, 1 or lower and it won't.

Comment: just tried it out to change the `PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL` to 1 and execution fails as expected. thx for the hint.

Comment: i think it is not possible to reproduce it in dbfiddle, because each section is executed in a different session. on my local db it works

Comment: i changed the session dynamicly: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=553263c80ed39ca33a459097d8dc6e97)*